# Batch file/XCopy Dependencies

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I am working on modifying an existing batch file. I want to copy over a file depending on whether there is a newer version of it from the source directory to a local machine. This works fine. I would like to then lock that file depending on if it was copied. If there was no copy, then simply move on to the line. How do I run a command based on if the output of xcopy was "1 File(s) copied" ?

Not sure on how to work use the output of the xcopy process to determine the next steps

Comment: `xcopy...|findstr /b /i /c:"0 file(s) copied">nul`  `if errorlevel 1 (echo files were copied) else (echo no files were copied)`  Easier to answer if we can see your code, even if it's just one line - just in case of something unexpected, and especially if it's within a `code block` (parenthesised sequence of commands)